# SharePoint 2013 Top Navigation increasing the size width of the menu drop box to fit text using JQuery

Tags: 2013, jquery, css, top-navigation

I have made the borders visible for the top navigation menu items. When the size of the text is not long the text appears to be fitting the menu drop box, However when the size increase of the text, it goes outside the box as shown below in the image. Requirement is not to break words.

[image]

Requirement is not to break words.

**Edit 1**

Below is the screenshot result tried out from Mihail's Answer.

The border of the box still does not stretch to the text size. Seems like with just plane css is it difficult to accomplish it. I believe may be css with jquery might be one option.
[image]

Comment: Use word-wrap:break-word

Comment: Thanjs Akhoy..Requirement is not to break words

Comment: can you post the code?

Comment: have you tried to float it?

Comment: Can you check whether the wrapper for that drop down has a fixed width? You could try overriding/removing that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To fix the problem with the text getting out of the box, use the following solution:

```
ul.dynamic {  
  width: auto !important;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Source:
http://blog.sharepointexperience.com/2014/10/increase-width-sharepoint-drop-down-navigation/

Answer (score 5):

You need the following piece of CSS to ensure that the menu items on the global navigation menus do not break into multiple lines and that the width of the drop-down menu extends to fit the length of the menu items' text:

```css
/* Disable menu text wrapping. */
#DeltaTopNavigation ul.dynamic {
  white-space: nowrap;
  word-wrap: normal;
  width: auto !important;
}
```

You can easily apply this CSS to an entire site collection by saving it as a **.css** file (e.g. "menu.css") and uploading it to SharePoint following this steps:

1. Navigate to the **root site** of a site collection.
2. Navigate to **Site Contents** of the site.
3. Navigate to the **Style Library** library.
4. Upload your **menu.css** file to the library and publish it.
5. Navigate to the **Site Settings**.
6. Click **Master Page** under **Look and Feel** section on the right column.
7. Click to expand the **Alternate CSS URL** section.
8. Select the "*Specify a CSS file to be used by this site and all sites that inherit from it:*" option.
9. Click the **Browse...** button and select the "*menu.css*" file from the Style Library.
10. Check the "*Reset all subsites to inherit this alternate CSS URL*" check box. Do this **ONLY** if the subsites in the site collection inherit the global navigation from the root site in the site collection.
11. Click **OK**.

Of course, you can apply the CSS fie only to specific sites, not to all sites in the site collection. Follow the same steps but ignore step **1** and **10**.

---

If you want to also reduce the distance between menu items and the arrow on the right-had side, add the following CSS to your **menu.css** file:

```css
/* Minimise space between menu item and arrow for sub menu items. */
.ms-core-listMenu-horizontalBox .dynamic-children.additional-background {
  padding-right: 12px;
}
```

You can of course change **12px** to another value to suit your needs.

---

> What I showed you above is the supported and recommended way by
>   MicroSoft. You can obviously use **jQuery** or **vanilla JS** to manipulate
>   the *style* property of the DOM elements which you can identify using the same HTML ids and classes I used above if your solution requires
>   it.

Comment: Hi Mihail, thank you for your answer, but still the borders are not increasing for the longer text size. Please see my edit 1 in the question with the screenshot

Comment: Hi spSTacker, apologies that I just realised that your problem is not about wrapping the menu item text, but expanding the drop-down width to fit the text. This leads me to think that somewhere you must have set the width of the drop-down menu. I would say you should try to remove the CSS/jQuery that you use to set the border, and then see what you get. If it works, then to add the border back, just add `border-right: 3px solid #43a0de;` to the `#DeltaTopNavigation ul.dynamic` block.

Comment: Actually see peac3maker's reply about adding `width: auto !important;` to the `#DeltaTopNavigation ul.dynamic` block of CSS. I have updated my CSS as well, but the credit should go to him. 
You can do this with jQuery as well, but jQuery involves additional overhead, plus you cannot elegantly/easily set the `width: auto !important` using jQuery.

Comment: Thank you Mihail.. for such prompt replies. Yes i am trying out the solution by peac3maker.

Comment: @spStacker: Did the solution work?

Answer (score 1):

Make the menu items stretch:

```
span.menu-item-text {
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Make the container resize to fit:

```
ul.dynamic {
  width: auto!important;
}
```